# Where to verify default font size in Foundation 6?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

The default font size is set to 100% of the browser style sheet, usually 16 pixels in Foundation 6. Where do I verify if it is really 16 pixels?

Comment: font-size of what? I believe foundation uses different font-size on some of its css classes and tags selectors

Comment: The default font size is set to 100% of the browser style sheet, usually 16 pixels in Foundation 6. That's from foundation itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have add font-size in body tag for default font size

```
body{font-size:16px;}
```